# KnexJS How to create multiple inner join

Tags: sql, database, query-builder, knex.js

I need to transform this SQL query to KnexJS query

```
SELECT
    Book.Title,
    Book.Number,
    Author.Name,
    Author_1.Name,
    Author_2.Name,
    Author_3.Name
FROM
    ((((Book)
INNER JOIN Author ON Book.AuthName = Author.Name)
INNER JOIN Author AS Author_1 ON Book.AuthName = Author_1.Name)
INNER JOIN Author AS Author_2 ON Book.AuthName = Author_2.Name)
INNER JOIN Author AS Author_3 ON Book.AuthName = Author_3.Name
WHERE Book.Title = "HelpMe" ORDER BY Book.Number;
```

I have read the doc here https://knexjs.org/#Builder-join but I barely understood how to use the given example to meet my need because there is no example for such multiple inner join.

Help me please

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Knex joins are chainable, so you can do this kind of thing:

```
knex
  .select('title', 'author1', 'author2')
  .from('books')
  .join('authors as author1', 'books.author_name', '=', 'author1.name')
  .join('authors as author2', 'books.author_name', '=', 'author2.name')
```

I suspect there's a problem with your example though, in that you're running basically the same comparison over and over again. Normally you would link to an `authors` table using a series of foreign keys (`author1id`, `author2id`) or more properly a join table since this is a MANY to MANY relationship:

```
knex
  .select('books.title', 'authors.name')
  .from('books')
  .join('books_authors', 'books.id', '=', 'books_authors.book_id')
  .join('authors', 'authors.id', '=', 'books_authors.author_id')
```

This grabs all the authors for the book, no matter how many there are, but requires an additional table consisting of only ids:

```
exports.up = knex =>
  knex.schema.createTable('books_authors', t => {
    t.integer('book_id').references('books.id')
    t.integer('author_id').references('authors.id')
  })

exports.down = knex => knex.schema.dropTable('books_authors')
```

Each time you add an author to a book, you'd also add the book's id and the author's id to the join table so that a relationship exists between the two. This way, each book can have one author or a hundred.

Comment: Thanks, didn't realize it would be so simple as that